# Grinder 2 console on linux

Tags: grinder

I am running Grinder2 console on Window. I want know how to run Grinder 2 console on Linux.

running net.grinder.Console is throwing the execption as below

Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program

-Amber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set DISPLAY where UI requires to be launched as

export DISPLAY=:0.0

install MochaXServer (http://www.mochasoft.dk/index.html)
and run server on windows PC